# How to close a jframe without closing the main program

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm creating a program to keep track of a list of DVD's. On the main page I have set up 2 JButtons. When the user clicks the one that says new, a new JFrame from another class comes up with fields to enter information about a new DVD. I'm trying to make a cancel button on this second frame work so that when one clicks the cancel button, it brings back up the main GUI and closes the new entry GUI. Code is below, I cant figure out how to do it.

Main GUI page

```
package dvdlibrary;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class bootPage extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form bootPage */
    public bootPage() {
        initComponents();
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("DVD Library");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(168, 11, -1, -1));

        jLabel2.setText("What would you like to do today?");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(113, 70, -1, -1));

        jButton1.setText("Create Record");
        jButton1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(50, 135, -1, -1));

        jButton2.setText("View Library");
        jButton2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton2MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(224, 135, 111, -1));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         




    }                                        

    private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
      if(evt.getSource()== jButton1)
           dvdlibrary.createEntry.createE();


    }                                     

    private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
       if(evt.getSource()== jButton2)
           dvdlibrary.movieChooser.movChoo();
    }                                     


    public static void bootP() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new bootPage().setVisible(true);
                new bootPage().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;


}
```

Create Entry page

```
package dvdlibrary;

public class createEntry extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public createEntry() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Title");

        jLabel2.setText("Genre");

        jLabel3.setText("Length");

        jLabel4.setText("Rating");

        jLabel5.setText("Description");

        jLabel6.setText("Year");

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton1.setText("Input");

        jButton2.setText("Load");

        jButton3.setText("Save");

        jButton4.setText("Cancel");
        jButton4.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jButton4MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 174, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 32, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField4)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 133, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(51, 51, 51)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(124, 124, 124)
                        .addComponent(jButton1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }                       

    private void jButton4MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      


    }                                     


    public static void createE() {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new createEntry().setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Answer (score 14):

I think you can also use [DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html):

> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE (the default for
> JInternalFrame)
>
> Hide and dispose of the window when the user closes it. This removes
> the window from the screen and frees up any resources used by it.

Answer (score 6):

Did you read the API to find out other values for the setDefaultCloseOperation(...) method?

You can use:

DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE - the frame will close. If this is the last open frame for the application then the JVM will terminate as well

HIDE_ON_CLOSE - the frame is just set to invisible.

> when user clicks the one that says new a new jframe from another class comes up with fields to enter information about a new dvd.

The real problem with your program is that you are using a frame as the popup window. You should be using a modal JDialog. An application should only ever have a single JFrame with multiple dialogs to gather additional information. A JDialog does not allow you to use EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 2):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: ok, i changed that in the frame settings, but now i cant close the window at all. What coding can i use so that the cancel button closes the window. SUDO   if actionperformed == cancel button
                                   Jframe.createEntry.Close
  or something like that

Comment: frame.setVisible(false); frame.dispose()

Comment: When I use `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` I get an IntelliJ warning to use `WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the case, make sure to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` on your JFrame when initializing, not setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

- DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE will terminate your application when the last JFrame
  is closed. EXIT_ON_CLOSE will terminate your application as soon as
  that JFrame is closed. HIDE_ON_CLOSE (default) will not terminate
  your application even if all JFrames are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and used `jFrameInstanceVariable.setVisible(false);` as the action that occured when I hit my CANCEL button. But every time I clicked the button that popped up the JFrame afterward, all the old content was still there in addition to the new content created from pressing the button.

I fixed this by making a new instance of JFrame every time the button is pressed that pops up the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the window without it actually closing the program, do:

```
f.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just hide the program, using `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` or `set.Visible(false)`, that is not a very good choice, because if you do something larger with more frames, the hidden frames will still be running, slowing down computer performance. The way, as other have said, is instead of using `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`, which will terminate the program when you click "X, closing all of the frames, use the following:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using a button like I think you said you were

```
this.dispose();
```

will do the trick..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `this.dispose();` inside the cancel button method.