# Java Swing: Inner JFrame class closes main window on close

Tags: java, swing, oop

I have the following structure of my program:the outer class `MainWindow`, the inner class `LoginWindow` and the private `JFrame` member `z`;

```
class MainWindow extends JFrame
{
    private JFrame z;    

    class LoginWindow extends JFrame
         {...}
    public LoginWindow makeLogin()
    {
      return new LoginWindow();
     }

    MainWindow()
     {
       ...
       z=new JFrame();
       z.setVisible(true);
     }

}

public class GUI
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow=new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);

        MainWindow.LoginWindow loginWindow=mainWindow.makeLogin();
        loginWindow.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

The main method returns three windows. When I close `z` window, only `z` closes. But when I close `MainWindow`/`LoginWindow`, everything shuts down. Why does this happen? Why the closing of the private JFrame member doesn't close the MainWindow, while closing its inner class' object closes everything down? How would I make so that closing the LoginWindow doesn't close the other two (while closing the MainWindow still closes everything).

Comment: Check camickr's answer in the [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268749/how-to-close-a-jframe-without-closing-the-main-program).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I make so that closing the LoginWindow doesn't close the other two (while closing the MainWindow still closes everything).

LoginWindow should not be a JFrame but rather a modal JDialog. This won't stop the Swing event thread when it is closed.

Comment: The other answers suggest disposing the window on close. What is better to use: `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` for `JFrame LoginWindow` or the `JDialog`?

Comment: It's better to give your GUI one JFrame, to avoid pushing windows at the user unless they are modal dialog windows (such as a login screen) or keep open dialog windows (like a separate floating menu or toolbar). Best in the running application to change JPanel views via a CardLayout.