# how to exit child jframe and not to exit parental JFrame

Tags: java

I have a JFrame window and has a component button in it.
when I click the button, it shows other a JFrame window.
the problem is when I click the close operation on the second window, it will
case both JFrame windows to close and program exit.
I want to close the second window only as I close it. not parent window either.
how can I do this in java.
by the way, what causes it to close the both window. actually I only closed the 
second only, but it exit the program unexpectedly.

Comment: Maybe a repeating question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268749/how-to-close-a-jframe-without-closing-the-main-program

Comment: Change the `defaultCloseOperation` to something other than `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);` on your JFrame when initializing, not `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

> DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE will terminate your application when the last JFrame is closed. 
>   EXIT_ON_CLOSE will terminate your application as soon as that JFrame is closed. 
>   HIDE_ON_CLOSE (default) will not terminate your application even if all JFrames are hidden.